# Answers disappearing, by the Roomba process

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-answers

With [this post in mind](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380596/an-answer-disappeared-twice), and particular [its answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380634/2827823), I found answers of mine suddenly disappearing, and no where to be found.

My own "recently deleted answers" were though, but it seems that answers deleted by the automated [Roomba process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) is not.

In some cases both question and answer is useful, but because of a bad worded title, lack of a vote or two and a few *"Roomba"* rules that happens to kick in within a given time frame, gets deleted.

I would like for those answers/questions to also be available in the "recently deleted ..." list, so one have a chance to act on them.

**Edit**

A clarification, I mean they should be within that list based on time of deletion, not on posted, or else many will never show up, and just because they were older doesn't mean they aren't useful.

Comment: *recently deleted answers* actually means *deleted, recent answers*.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Well, you can see your own answers in that list for a while, which is of course what I mean, not for them to never disappear

Comment: the problem is that the implementation differs from the label. When you go to *recently deleted answers*, you are actually shown *recently posted (age < 60 days) answers by me that were deleted*.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Yes, I am aware of that, and now I am asking if also my answers/questions that were deleted by someone else could be in the same list. After all, they are mine.

Comment: they should be on this list. The only reason I know that they were posted more than 60 days ago. Answers deleted after question deletion stay in the list. (I verified.)

Comment: Okay...I mean they should be within that list based on time of deletion, not on posted, or else many will never show up, and just because they were older doesn't mean they aren't useful.

Comment: That wasn't Roomba. It was deleted due to the user being Destroyed, causing all posts to be deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can't say, were told by the answerer I linked Meta SO post it was Roomba. Still, what/whom ever deleted it, I would like it to be found in the list.

Comment: @LGSon Roomba leaves a note in the revisions (something with DeletedAbandoned.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I haven't seen anything under my "Activity" tab, those 2 answers just disappeared.

Comment: It seems that SO doesn't want to change the policy about this, unfortunately. Proposition: [A user should *always* be able to find its own content, even if deleted silently by Roomba 2 years before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364720/list-own-deleted-questions-in-profile).